# About custom field in default_articles.php

Tags: joomla-3.x

I've already created a custom field called "part-no", and I want to show the "part-no" that exist in all articles in the same category. But now it only show the "part-no" from last article, how to show it from all articles? I don't want to use table.

part-no = NO1 in article1,
part-no = NO2 in article2,
part-no = NO3 in article3,

Now it only shows N03

I want to show: N01, N02, NO3

I overided default_articles.php like below:

```
<?php
defined ('_JEXEC') or die();
JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers/html');
use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;

    // Create some shortcuts.
$params    = &$this->item->params;

// Check for at least one editable article
$isEditable = false;

if (!empty($this->items))
{
    foreach ($this->items as $article)
    {
        if ($article->params->get('access-edit'))
        {
            $isEditable = true;

        }
    }
}
?>

<?php if (!empty($this->items)) : ?>
<?php foreach($article->jcfields as $jcfield){
    $article->jcFields[$jcfield->name] = $jcfield;
}
?>

<?php echo $article->jcFields['part-no']->value; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `<?php echo $article->jcFields['part-no']->value; ?>` is only called once (after the loop is finished iterating) -- so you will only have access to the final iteration's data.  Also, I don't know that this check makes any sense: `<?php if (!empty($this->items)) : ?>` because you are not trying to access `$this->items` inside of it.

Comment: Thanks very much, Mickmackusa. I will delete <?php if (!empty($this->items)) : ?>, is there any way to call always (not once)?

Comment: Generally speaking, don't you just want to do this? https://3v4l.org/5ccG5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I solved it:

```
<?php foreach ($this->items as $article) : ?>
<?php if ($article->params->get('access-edit'))
        {
            $isEditable = true;
            break;
        }
?>

<?php foreach($article->jcfields as $jcfield){
    $article->jcFields[$jcfield->name] = $jcfield;
}
?>
<div><?php echo $article->jcFields['part-no']->value; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```